# Nomeclatura classificativa de episódios de uma série

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, vocabulário

Apesar do título pomposo, a pergunta é quase simples.

Uma série, de TV por exemplo, independente de sobreviver tempo o bastante para se estender por mais de uma temporada, tem seus episódios numerados cardinalmente, e a partir da segunda temporada, a maioria das séries reiniciam a contagem para o primeiro episódio.

Porém, sites como IMDB, por exemplo, mantém esse registro sequencial dando origem ao chamado **absolute**. Ex: Em uma série de duas temporadas, cada uma com 20 episódios, o primeiro da segunda temporada é chamado de *absolute 21*

Pois bem, no contexto classificativo que eu procuro, como seria chamado cada um dos componentes dessa nomenclatura? Temos a **temporada**, claro, que é bem óbvio, e depois temos o "número". Mas seria apenas "número" mesmo ou teria alguma palavra mais específica ou de melhor significância?

Além disso, mesmo que uma lista de episódios seja um **conjunto** (matemático) acredito que *elemento*, nome dos membros de um conjunto, não seria apropriado.

Uma possível restrição é que eu queria tentar evitar a palavra **episódio** pois, como usarei em programação, os dados ficariam armazenados num *array* (conjunto), mais ou menos assim:

```
episódio
  temporada: 2
  palavra_que_nao_tenho_certeza: 1
  absolute: 21
```

E se eu usasse **episodio** pra essa descrição em particular, na hora de fazer a leitura dos dados, eu teria algo como `episodio.episodio`, o que pode gerar confusão para quem ler.

Comment: Não percebo bem o que estás a perguntar. Podes indicar uma frase exemplo? Já agora, o teu exemplo de "um array mais ou menos assim" não parecer conter array nenhum; querias dizer "um array com dados mais ou menos assim"?

Comment: Sigh... Espero que essa comunidade não se torne mais um Stack Overflow da vida. Mas, vamos lá... **Não existe frase**, é uma pergunta mais conceitual, que precisa ser mais interpretada do que simplesmente lida pois eu **realmente** só tenho como prover um background detalhado. Esse array de dados não tem **nada** a ver com a pergunta em si. Foi apenas um exemplo de como vou usar a palavra, seja ela qual for, para deixar bem evidente o porquê de ela, preferencialmente, não seja **episodio**.

Comment: todas as comunidades do SE carregam um pouco desse mal, infelizmente... umas mais, outras menos.

Comment: *Capítulo* não serviria? Talvez mudar o nome da array para fazer [nome da array].episodio ajude na programação também.

Comment: Pensei nisso. Na verdade até li o artigo da Wikipedia sobre "TV Series" e, embora faça bastante sentido, ainda ficou estranho de se ler no código. Mas enfim, acabei renomeando o tal array pra `show` e o que eu precisava ficou `show.episodio`. Não é assim uma Brastemp, mas...

Answer (score 1):

Alternativas para a palavra episódio são: *capítulo* e *parte*.

> Série X temporada Y, capítulo Z.
>
> Série X temporada Y, parte W.

Um código alternativo que se usa para indicar a unidade de lançamento de uma série é SXY_WZ. S03_12 seria episódio 12 da temporada 3. S02_01 seria episódio 1 da temporada 2.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Relativo*** (vs *Absoluto*)

O valor de contagem que se estende por toda a duração da série foi chamado de valor absoluto. Seguindo a mesma lógica, o outro valor indicado poderia ter o nome de relativo, por ser uma contagem "interna" em cada temporada.

Por exemplo, se uma série teve 10 episódios na primeira temporada, a segunda começa com o número 11 em absoluto. Este episódio será o número 1 **relativamente ao início** da segunda temporada.